# Why would a new post from a 1 rep user without any activity have its review invalidated?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I checked [When is a review task "completed" or "invalidated"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164288/323179) but don't see any reason why these reviews would be invalidated. That post doesn't list any hidden actions (e.g., flagging, entering another review queue) as being able to invalidate these types of reviews.

- [Webapps first answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/158992). There's no visible activity on this answer—the review is just invalidated.
- [Stack Overflow first question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31471557) (deleted; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4DyS.png); [timeline screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUDrB.png)). I can't see this post anymore but I [saw this confusing invalidated review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377778/timeline-for-some-posts-returns-500-error-for-moderators#comment1260869_377778) before the post was closed and deleted. There was apparently a deleted comment on this question that I couldn't see, but that shouldn't invalidate the review. (It is completely expected that the *second* review item, in Triage, got invalidated, since it happened mere minutes after the question was closed.)

It's possible that the [faq-proposed] is wrong about how things work, but I'm tentatively tagging this with [bug].

Comment: My recollection is that a downvote from outside the queue can kick a post out. But I'm not upon the details, I've given up reviewing.

Comment: @philipxy Not according to the linked post it can't. Also there's no evidence that anyone downvoted since this 1-rep user on Webapps only has an answer with 0 score.

Comment: @Laurel in addition, the SO post you linked to has received no votes. Unless they were removed in the grace period but I think it's unlikely.

Comment: @VLAZ Can you get a link to the review itself? I wonder if I would be able to see it without 10k. (Considering it was like a year and a half ago, it's pretty incredible that I even remember it existed at all, much less any of the details.)

Comment: The SO post? It had two reviews (both invalidated): [First questions](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31471557) ([screenshot if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4DyS.png)) and [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/31471598) ([screenshot if needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHKd6.png)). And [here is a screenshot of the timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUDrB.png) to show when it was booted out of different queues. For FQ - it exited the queue 8 minutes after being posted. For Triage - it exited after it was closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The First Posts queues are a bit special in that they tend to get processed *first*, but posts that end up in those two queues can also be eligible for other queues that are a bit more tailored to a certain situation. First Questions can end up in Triage and First Answers can end up in Low Quality Posts.

When these queues were revamped, we modified the behavior to create the First Posts tasks immediately upon post creation without going through the syncing process, to get them into review faster. That inherently means that other queues don't get a chance to pull them in before there is already a review task for them. If a post is subsequently eligible for one of the other queues, we create that task and then the next sync of First Posts will invalidate the existing task in that queue in favor of the newly created one in the more tailored queue.

In your examples:

- The answer ended up in Low Quality Posts 21 minutes later, causing the First Answers task to be invalidated 9 minutes after that.
- The question ended up in Triage 3 minutes later, causing the First Questions task to be invalidated 5 minutes after that.

The FAQ was just never updated to call out this new case.

Answer (score 2):

If someone flags or votes to delete a post via the review queue then they can select "Other action" that [kicks the post out of the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369837/other-action-in-first-answers-doesnt-fully-complete-the-review/369947#369947).

I can see why the answer you link would be flagged as "Not an answer" and the question could easily be flagged as "Needs Details or Clarity"

Comment: Well we need someone with enough rep to confirm that though.

Comment: Only moderators can see flags.

Comment: Oh, thought the review history would show it. (i.e. need to look for the history of items for same post, then you can find where someone chose the Other Action. No? e.g. [random review item on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/35429780), where it says "Reviewed" which means choosing other action)

Comment: Does this result in the review being *invalidated* ("This item is no longer reviewable.") or does it say "[User] reviewed this [timestamp]: Reviewed" and mark the review as "Reviewed"? The reviews I'm asking about did not have any reviewers listed because they were invalidated.